How to avoid overwriting GitLab CI variables when using Terraform
I am new to Terraform and am trying to provision my GitLab project using it.
This works so far, but I am also creating keys that must not be reset with every run.
Therefore, the GitLab CI variables should only be created if they do not already exist.
Unfortunately, I have no idea how to formulate this in Terraform.
This is the relevant part of my configuration:
variable "env_scopes_all" {
  type = list(object({
    scope    = string
    env_type = string
  }))
  default = [
    { scope = "prod/live", env_type = "live" },
    { scope = "prod/staging", env_type = "staging" },
    { scope = "prod/review-*", env_type = "review" }
  ]
}

data "external" "vapid_keys" {
  count = length(var.env_scopes_all)
  program = ["/bin/sh", "-c", <<-EOF
    pem=$(openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout)
    private_key=$(echo "$pem" | openssl ec -outform DER 2>/dev/null | tail -c +8 | head -c 32 | base64 -w 0 | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-')
    public_key=$(echo "$pem" | openssl ec -pubout -outform DER 2>/dev/null | tail -c 65 | base64 -w 0 | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-')

    printf '{"private_key":"%s","public_key":"%s"}\n' "$private_key" "$public_key"
  EOF
  ]
}

resource "gitlab_project_variable" "VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY" {
  count             = length(var.env_scopes_all)
  project           = gitlab_project.elybird.id
  key               = "VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY"
  value             = data.external.vapid_keys[count.index].result.private_key
  description       = "Base64-encoded VAPID private key for push notifications"
  environment_scope = var.env_scopes_all[count.index].scope
  masked            = false
  protected         = false
  raw               = true
  variable_type     = "env_var"
}

resource "gitlab_project_variable" "VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY" {
  count             = length(var.env_scopes_all)
  project           = gitlab_project.elybird.id
  key               = "VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY"
  value             = data.external.vapid_keys[count.index].result.public_key
  description       = "Base64-encoded VAPID public key for client push subscription"
  environment_scope = var.env_scopes_all[count.index].scope
  masked            = false
  protected         = false
  raw               = true
  variable_type     = "env_var"
}


I think you need to expand your question. What do you mean the variables should only be created if they do not already exists. do you mean if they dont exist in the terraform state file? terraform should be smart enough to look up the vars actual value in gitlab and set it to the value terraform has in the event of configuration drift.

The GitLab CI variable - not a Terraform variable - should only be created if it does not already exist. In fact, with the configuration presented, a new value is generated with each run. It may need to be queried before and set conditionally.

A new value is created with each run because data blocks run every time and in your data block your creating a new set of keys each time. If you want a set of public and private keys why not just use https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tls/latest/docs/resources/private_key which will generate the keys only once

"Use of this resource for production deployments is not recommended." - I don't think it's needed to store the value somewhere else as in the GitLab CI variables, but "tls_private_key" stores it in the statefile.

But your storing the the private key in the state file anyway when you reference it in the gitlab_project_variable resource block. Terraform will read the value from the data block and then store the actual key as an attribute of the resource. So by not using the TLS provider your not preventing your private key being stored unencrypted in the state file. Its still there. Also production best practice would be to store that state file in remote file storage like S3 which provides encryption at rest and in transit to the statefile its self is encrypted at the storage layer.

If you really dont want to use the TLS module (Which many many people do use) then you could add a lifecycle block to the gitlab_project_variable telling it to ignore changed on the value attribute. That way the first time you run it it will generate the resource. When you run it a 2nd time and the private key in the data resource changes. terraform should ignore it https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#ignore_changes

from the docs The ignore_changes feature is intended to be used when a resource is created with references to data that may change in the future, but should not affect said resource after its creation.

I don't think it's possible to use ignore_changes, because the data is evaluated every time and so the value changes. But I will try both suggestions later.

After having a discussion in the comments I am going to add this as an answer here around using ignore_changes. I personally still dont feel like this is the best option for you. But thats up to you to decide.
I am using a simple example Since I dont have gitlab setup to demo this. The example uses a var in the external data source but this should be similar to your example
variable "custom_length" {
    type = number
    description = "Custom length for the random_pet resource"
}

data "external" "foo" {
  program = ["powershell", "-Command", "echo '{\"counter\":\"${var.custom_length}\"}'"]
}

resource "random_pet" "foo" {
  length = data.external.foo.result["counter"]
  lifecycle {ignore_changes = [length]}
}

output "counter" {
  value = data.external.foo.result["counter"]
}

output "pet_length" {
  value = random_pet.foo.length
}

If we run this you can see that on the first apply it creates 1 resource. On the 2nd apply with a different value it does indeed ignore the change in the attribute after its created. It does not create or destroy or change any resources, only the output changes.
I have added the output only for reference so you can see the data block output is changing but terraform doesnt change the resources because we are ignoring that attributes value.
First Create
$ terraform apply --var=custom_length=3 --auto-approve
data.external.foo: Reading...
data.external.foo: Read complete after 0s [id=-]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # random_pet.foo will be created
  + resource "random_pet" "foo" {
      + id        = (known after apply)
      + length    = 3
      + separator = "-"
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  + counter    = "3"
  + pet_length = 3
random_pet.foo: Creating...
random_pet.foo: Creation complete after 0s [id=needlessly-wanted-hare]

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

counter = "3"
pet_length = 3

Second Apply (Changed value)
$ terraform apply --var=custom_length=5 --auto-approve
data.external.foo: Reading...
data.external.foo: Read complete after 0s [id=-]
random_pet.foo: Refreshing state... [id=needlessly-wanted-hare]

Changes to Outputs:
  ~ counter    = "3" -> "5"

You can apply this plan to save these new output values to the Terraform state, without changing any real infrastructure.

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

counter = "5"
pet_length = 3

You can see in the 2nd apply there is no changes in the infra, the outputs show that the external resource is returning 5, but the random_pet keeps its value as 3 and terraform decides there is no change to be made in the resource.

Yes, it works, great, thanks :-)
I agree that it would better to use the tls_private_key resource, but I can't get it to work to generate a VAPID compatible key. So I just use the lifecycle for now.
